# Norm of the product of a matrix and a vector with constant norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an invariant matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with known entries and a vector function $\vec{x}(\theta)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ with one variable $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$, if $\|\vec{x}\| = c$ (a known scalar), what's the value of $\vec{x}^\top A \vec{x}$?

Comment: This will depend on the matrix. And when you say "constant," does that mean the entries of $x$ depend on something, and maybe the entries of $A$ also? More context may provide clearer answers.

Comment: @leslietownes Thanks for the suggestion. I'll modify the question.

Comment: At the moment I still don't see enough information to conclusively answer the question. Geometrically, $x$ is traveling around a sphere of radius $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in some way that depends on $\theta$. The specifics of how $A$ acts on $x$ still definitely depend on $A$. Upper bounds for the magnitude of the scalar you are trying to evaluate can be obtained from the entries of $A$, but they don't tell you the value of the quantity you're interested in, only an upper bound. At this level of detail, that is about it. It will be interesting to see what others do with this problem.

Comment: @leslietownes This is just a general problem that popped up in my mind without many details. Thanks for sharing your thoughts :))

Comment: One observation (independent of $A$) is that for nice paths, the velocity of the path will be perpendicular to the path vector itself (as you'd expect if you imagine traveling along the surface of a sphere). This comes e.g. from differentiating $\langle x, x \rangle = c^2$ with respect to $\theta$ and using the properties of differentiation.